# WinRM cannot process the request. Error 0x80090311

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication

I have to 2 systems (SR01 & SR02) with local administrators account. Both the systems are in the same domain. The local admin accounts are same with different password. These machines are VM's.

When I run a enter-pssession from SR01 to SR02 it throws the below error.

Error:
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server SR02.Domain.com failed with the following error
message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using
Kerberos authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or
use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (SR02.Domain.com:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRem
   otingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

Script Used:

$cred=Get-Credential

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "SR02" -Credential $cred

Comment: Give this a try: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tspring/2014/06/23/viewing-and-purging-cached-kerberos-tickets/

Clearing all cashed kerberos tickets

Comment: No luck. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get past this error by adding the remote computer to my computer's WinRM TrustedHosts

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="remoteComputerName"}'
```