# PowerShell 5.1 What is wrong with my New-PSSession syntax

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Environment:
PowerShell 5.1
Windows 2016 Standard
Windows 10 Pro

Just asking here if syntax is fundamentally correct...

```
$hostSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostName -Credential $cred
$versionFolder = "c:\temp"
$sspLatestVer = Invoke-Command -Session $hostSession -ScriptBlock { param($path) (Get-ChildItem $path | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name } -ArgumentList $versionFolder
```

### Update:

The following works on one machine but not on another:

```
$versionFolder = "\\COMPUTER01\c$\temp"
$sspLatestVer = (Get-ChildItem $versionFolder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name
```

Error Message for machine that doesn't work

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\COMPUTER01\c$\temp' because it does not exist.
At C:\temp\candidate2.ps1:24 char:18
+ $sspLatestVer = (Get-ChildItem $versionFolder | Sort-Object LastWrite ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\COMPUTER01\c$\temp:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

OP Error Message:

```
New-PSSession : [COMPUTER01] Connecting to remote server COMPUTER01 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using 
Kerberos authentication: We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again. If you previously signed in on 
this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At C:\Users\RSTEST\Documents\candidate2.ps1:17 char:16
+ ... hostSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostName -Credential $cred
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticationFailed,PSSessionOpenFailed
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\RSTEST\Documents\candidate2.ps1:19 char:41
+ $sspLatestVer = Invoke-Command -Session $hostSession -ScriptBlock { p ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Remove-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\RSTEST\Documents\candidate2.ps1:20 char:24
+ Remove-PSSession -Name $hostSession
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-PSSession], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSSessionCommand
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax. Read the error message

Comment: I think this is better asked at serverfault

Comment: As the path contains a `$`, I would use a literal string (single quotes) and `-LiteralPath` to be at  the safe side: `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\COMPUTER01\c$\temp'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here:

First, see [WinRM cannot process the request. Error 0x80090311](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45989166/18815893)

If the remote system is in the same domain, and you are already logged in with a domain account that is an administrator on that system, then there would be no need to specify a credential for `New-PSSession`

If the systems are in different forests that have a trust with each other, note that there is a need to use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the remote host for Kerberos authentication to function correctly.

---

Second, regarding:

```
$versionFolder = "\\COMPUTER01\c$\temp"
```

Note that remote sessions normally do **not** have access to network shares, even when presumably running under the credentials of an administrative user.

This is known as the "second hop problem".  There have been various posts about it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-5.1

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/

This may work from COMPUTER01 itself, since it could be aliased to local drive access.